How do we change the font color of ant design charts X and Y Axis Labels
I have spent way to much time trying to find out how to do this, I have tried the only example ive found to no avail
  yAxis: {
    label: {
      style: {
        fill: 'blue', // Change the color of y-axis labels to blue
      },
    },
  },


You can access an object with the key axis inside your config object.
This object has many properties that can be applied to it.
It's structured the following way:
const config = {
  axis: {
    x: {},
    y: {},
  },
}

The property you are looking for is called labelFill. You can view all the available properties here.

The following example creates a red font color for your X-axis and a blue color for your Y-axis:
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Line } from '@ant-design/plots';

const DemoLine = () => {
  const config = {
    data: {
      type: 'fetch',
      value: 'https://assets.antv.antgroup.com/g2/indices.json',
    },
    xField: (d) => new Date(d.Date),
    yField: 'Close',
    colorField: 'Symbol',
    normalize: { basis: 'first', groupBy: 'color' },
    axis: {
      x: { title: 'X Title', labelFill: 'red' },
      y: { title: 'Y Title', labelFill: 'blue' },
    },
  };
  return <Line {...config} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<DemoLine />, document.getElementById('container'));


Code-Sandbox

You can view more examples here.

Thank you so much that worked perfectly!
